# Explicit form for $\sum_p \ln(\ln(p))$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Riemann gave an explicit form for the counting function of the primes.

Is there an explicit form for the counting function $f(x) = \sum_p \ln(\ln(p))$ where the sum is over $p$ : the number of primes smaller than $x$ such that $\ln(\ln(p)) >0$ ?

Comment: Which explicit form do you mean for $\pi(x)$ ?

Comment: @lhf with explicit forms I mean as a sum over the zero's.
Just like riemann's formula or Mangold's formula is over the sum of zero's of the riemann zeta.
I believe that $\pi(x)$ is UNIQUELY expressible as the sum over zero's of the riemann zeta , right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you'd approach all the information you want about the quantity is:
\begin{align*}
\log f(x) = \sum_{p\le x} \log\log p &= \int_{2-}^x (\log\log t) \,d\pi(t) \\
&= \pi(x) \log\log x - \int_2^x \frac{\pi(t)}{t\log t}dt.
\end{align*}
(The penultimate expression is a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, but you can ignore it and even prove by hand that the second and fourth expressions are equal.) From this you can see for example that $\log f(x) = \pi(x) \log\log x + O(x/\log^2x)$. Exponentiating you get a lower bound like $f(x) > (\log x)^{\pi(x) - Cx(\log\log x)/\log^2x}$ for some constant $C>0$

I think we can use this to get An explicit form by considering the integral above.